# Testcafe falsely asserting false

Tags: node.js, testcafe, gui-testing

Testcafe is yielding the following result

```
) AssertionError: expected 'Field \'HANDLING POINT\' is required.' to deeply equal 'Field \'HANDLING POINT\' is required.'

      + expected - actual

      -Field 'HANDLING POINT' is required.
      +Field 'HANDLING POINT' is required.
```

from the below code

```
await t.expect(Selector(".jsError").child().child().innerText).eql("Field 'HANDLING POINT' is required.");
```

I'm quite confused as I've tried everything I can thing of and yet the same code works fine for different text.

This is the html I am testing agaisnt. I I test for the shift field message, all is well

`<span class="jsError"><ul><li>Field 'HANDLING&nbsp;POINT' is required.</li><li>Field 'SHIFT' is required.</li></ul></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Non-Breaking Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), represented by `&nbsp;` in HTML, is a different character from a regular space. You can use the escape sequence `\xA0` to represent it in the JavaScript string literal you're comparing against.